# How do I make faces combine correctly?

Tags: org-mode, faces, themes

Example:

[image: Example]

How do I make faces combine correctly? I am not opposed to providing a separate set of instructions for each combination (per theme), but do not know how to do that.

Comment: You need to look at each face, e.g., by placing the cursor at that position and typing `C-u C-x =` and then following the links to view the face settings.  If for example the face responsible for colorizing the TODO has a height of 160 and the face responsible for colorizing the Header Level has a height of 180, and the date face has a height of 140, well, in that case, the mystery is solved.  Look for anything that is different among the faces that might be responsible for different sizes -- e.g., the family such as Courier versus Helvetica; height, etc.]  You can customize each face.

Comment: I want to make the `org-todo` face have the correct height _in the context_ of the surrounding face. It needs to have different heights when surrounded by (or combined with) the `org-level-1` face and the `org-level-2` face.

Comment: In general, faces are global and do not change their height on the fly based upon the context.  It is possible to make faces buffer local, but that is not your question.  The feature you seek is not built-in to the best of my knowledge and would require more modification of the source code than will fit into a concise answer.  You may be interested in researching the usage of overlays, but again, this is going to require some to a lot of work on your part.